# literary or rhetorical definition

Tags: single-word-requests, rhetoric, literary-techniques

Looking for single word definition for a question or riddle that seemingly has no answer. Designed to confuse. Not paradox or conundrum. I.e "What is the sounds of on hand clapping?"

Comment: This is  called a (Zen) koan.

Comment: "One hand" or "on hand"?

Answer (score 1):

That would be a Zen (short) story  ;-) . See:

http://www.101zenstories.com/index.php?story=21

Comment: For which the loan-word *Kōan* is often used, though not all kōans are riddles.

Comment: Has "koan" entered the English lexicon? I see it on Dictionary.com but have never read or heard it in common usage.

Answer (score 0):

A *[paradox](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/paradox?q=paradox)*?

> a seemingly absurd or contradictory statement or proposition which when investigated may prove to be well founded or true:
>   *the uncertainty principle leads to all sorts of paradoxes, like the particles being in two places at once*

A *[conundrum](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conundrum?q=conundrum)*?

> a confusing and difficult problem or question:
>   one of the most difficult conundrums for the experts

An *[enigma](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/enigma?q=enigma)*?

> a person or thing that is mysterious or difficult to understand:
>   *Madeleine was still an enigma to him*

Answer (score 0):

you could call it a ***catch-22*** defined in the dictionary as

> 1. a frustrating situation in which one is trapped by contradictory regulations or conditions.
> 2. any illogical or paradoxical problem or situation; dilemma.
> 3. *a condition, regulation, etc., preventing the resolution of a problem or situation; catch.*

Answer (score 0):

- Intractable
- Gordian Knot
- Dilemma
- Inconsistency
- Round Square
- Mutally Exclusive
- Unrecognizable Pattern
- Wild Goose Chase
- Inconsistent Model
- Nonsense
- Time Waster
- Logical Illogic
- Circular Logic
- Axiom

Answer (score 0):

I recognize that this does not actually answer the question, but… I think there is a modern tendency to insist on having a word for something, at any cost.  I suggest that you allow the possibility of having to use more than one word.

For the definitive feature of the expression, I would use “paradox” or “incoherent” (or possibly “internally inconsistent”)… or just “meaningless”.

I think here I would use “incoherent question” — given your desire for conciseness.  With the luxury of using enough words:  “a question built around an internally inconsistent concept”.

(The term “meaningless” includes things that are quite without meaning, which is not useful here.)